# Watch and compile coffeescript in multiple folders and vendor javascript files in specific order, also organize sass and html templates

Tags: javascript, build, coffeescript, sass, cakefile

I have a directory structure like this:

```
+ src
  |
  | - modules
  |   |
  |   | - auth
  |   |   |
  |   |   | - auth.coffee
  |   |   | - auth.sass
  |   |   | - login.html
  |   |   | - logout.html
  |   |
  |   | - navigation
  |   |   |
  |   |   | - navigation.coffee
  |   |   | - navigation.sass
  |   |   | - navbar.html
  |   |  
  | - scripts
  |   |
  |   | - vendor
  |   |   |
  |   |   | - underscore.js
  |   |   | - angular.js
  |   |
  |   | - app.coffee
  |   | - router.coffee
  |
  | - styles
  |   |
  |   | - config.sass
  |   | - style.sass
```

I want to:

1. Watch all `.coffee`, `.sass` and `.html` files and do steps 2 and 3 when a file has changed
2. Compile the `.coffee` and `.sass` files.

   For both i need to specify dependencies (or: a specific ordering).

   - Coffeescript

     - compile `scripts/vendor/underscore.js`
     - then `scripts/vendor/angular.js`
     - then `scripts/*.js`
     - then `modules/**/*.js`
   - SASS

     - compile `styles/config.sass`
     - then `styles/style.sass`
     - then `modules/**/*.sass`
3. Collect all `.js`, `.css` and `.html` files and organize them for the public folder.

This is the desired output

```
+ public
  |
  | - partials
  |   |
  |   | - auth
  |   |   |
  |   |   | - login.html
  |   |   | - logout.html
  |   |
  |   | - navigation
  |   |   |
  |   |   | - navbar.html
  |   |  
  | - scripts
  |   |
  |   | - app.js
  |
  | - styles
  |   |
  |   | - app.css
```

I tried many tools, but couldn't get the desired result. For example [Flour](http://ricardo.cc/cake-flour/) for the Coffeescript had problems with wildcards in compile methods.

I think the best thing would be a Cakefile that does everything for me. How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why compile underscore or angular? Just link to the minified version on a CDN. You might be able to get better performance by packing those together with your app js, I don't have a solid yes/no answer on this, you'll have to research.

I think you should be able to accomplish this with [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). My config isn't exactly what you want but:

```
  # Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig
    watch:
      coffee:
        files: ['app/assets/src/coffee/**/*.coffee', 'app/assets/src/coffee/*.coffee', 'test/*.coffee', '!**/screencaps/**', 'app/webserver.coffee']
        tasks: ['coffee:dev', 'replace', 'mochaTest']

  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-coffee")
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch')
```

Etc. [Grunt uses glob for file pattern matching](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks). For what you want to do I'd set up a chain of watch commands:

1. Watch for a change in `src/modules/*.coffee`
2. Compile (and optionally [uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify)) all coffee to js, move to `public/scripts`.
3. Do the same for SASS files.

Comment: you are completely right about not compiling js files. it should have been: compile coffescripts and concat them with all js files